# R: Shuffle array elements of selected dimensions

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, shuffle

Problem: Given a multidimensional array, shuffle its elements in some selected dimensions. Ideally, **the array should be shuffled *in situ* / in place**, because a second one might not fit into my memory.

For example, given an array `a`  with 4 dimensions, assign to each `a[x,y,z,]` another value `a[x2,y2,z2,]` for all `x,y,z`, where `x2,y2,z2` are chosen randomly from the set of indices of their respective dimension.

Example array:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- array(data=sample(1:9, size=3*3*3*2, replace=T), dim=c(3,3,3,2))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in R than using 3 nested for-loops? The naive approach I tried:

```
x.rand <- floor(runif( n=3, min = 1, max = 3 + 1)); # max and min will not be generated by runif()
y.rand <- floor(runif( n=3, min = 1, max = 3 + 1));
z.rand <- floor(runif( n=3, min = 1, max = 3 + 1));
for( i in 1:3) {
  for( j in 1:3) {
    for( k in 1:3) {
      tmp <- a[i,j,k, ];
      a[i,j,k,] <- a[x.rand[i], y.rand[j], z.rand[k], ];
      a[x.rand[i], y.rand[j], z.rand[k], ] <- tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

But for larger arrays I run into performance issues.

Comment: I am almost sure that the answer to your question is yes but I need a bit more explanations about what you do with vector `a`

Comment: Added my own (bad) approach. I hope this clarifies what I want to do.

Comment: If you have `n` dimensions, will you always want to shuffle `n-1` dimensions? If yes, is the non-shuffled dimension always the last one?

Comment: `sample` would indeed be a better choice. However, I do not drop any of my data since even for duplicate indices I am always swapping to entries, so how is any data lost?

Comment: Sorry, I had to adjust my question one more time: The shuffling should take place *in situ*, see first paragraph. I just do not have enough RAM for a second array :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Pop had the right idea before he removed his answer but you'll have to be careful to use `sample` if you don't want to drop data (we're not swapping "columns" two-by-two anymore but selecting all of them once in a different order)

```
x.rand <- sample(dim(a)[1])
y.rand <- sample(dim(a)[2])
z.rand <- sample(dim(a)[3])
a[] <- a[x.rand, y.rand, z.rand, ]
```

Assuming an array with larger dimensions, a more programmatic approach could be:

```
idx <- lapply(dim(a), sample) # shuffle dimensions
idx[[4]] <- TRUE  # the only fixed dimension
a[] <- do.call(`[`, c(list(a), idx))
```

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! The second solution runs through even for big arrays. Why exactly does the first code create a copy of `a` while the second one does not? What is the difference between `a[indices]`, `\`[\`(a,indices)` and `do.call(\`[\`,indices)`?